# Tracking failed ERROR [solr.tracker.AbstractTracker] [SolrTrackerScheduler_Worker-10]

Tags: java, maven

Tracking failed ERROR [solr.tracker.AbstractTracker] [SolrTrackerScheduler_Worker-10]

Here is the error log:

> ```
>  org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 04250712 GetModelsDiff return status is 403
>   at org.alfresco.solr.client.SOLRAPIClient.getModelsDiff(SOLRAPIClient.java:1157)
>   at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.ModelTracker.trackModelsImpl(ModelTracker.java:249)
>   at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.ModelTracker.trackModels(ModelTracker.java:207)
>   at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.ModelTracker.doTrack(ModelTracker.java:167)
>   at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.AbstractTracker.track(AbstractTracker.java:185)
>   at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.TrackerJob.execute(TrackerJob.java:47)
>   at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:216)
>   at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:563)
> ```

Comment: try if it solves your issue https://community.alfresco.com/thread/178049-getmodelsdiff-return-status-is-403

Comment: GetModelsDiff returns 403. 403 usually means no permission. Check if the current session or user has permission to do this action.